# Active Record or DataMapper for multi join tables

Tags: php, sql, activerecord, datamapper

Currently I am looking to refactor my code in php to use Active Record or DataMapper. I have a complex sql query where one table is the base and to it I join multiple tables in several levels, ie, join a table to which another table is joined.

For example:

```
Select <list of columns>
from main_table
left join table1
left join table2 as t1
left join table2 as t2
left join table3
left join table4 on table3.key = table4.key
left join ( select * from table5 ) as t3
left join ( select * from table6 where id in ( select id from table7 ) ) as t4
where <conditions>
```

What is better to use? Active Record or DataMapper.
Also I want it to be handy to uptade or insert to the main table. And also do some show/output functions. Handle input from user.

Any advise is welcome.

Comment: You said you wanted to be handy in maintaining and updating tables then that just echo “Active Record”. But on a second thought if you already have your business logic with your Object already then maybe DataMapper is better of.

Comment: I do retrieve rows from the tables based on a where condition which searches thru several columns on all of the tables and show the rows using datatable. Also users can edit any row, but only changes a actually made only in main table.

Comment: If I could clarify, the above code you mentioned, the data you just fetched, is it a representation of a single model?

Comment: I do not really understand how the single model can look.

Comment: I suggest you should use a data mapper as data access pattern. And for complex data you need a to implement a repository pattern